# Way to apply datatype YEAR (MariaDB) to model's attribute

Tags: node.js, attributes, mariadb, sequelize.js

In MariaDB there exists the datatype `YEAR` which contains - you wouldn't expect this - just and only a year like for example *2021*, *2930* or *1784*.
Rigth now I am setting up Sequelize as ORM for MariaDB. And for a reason I don't understand, I can't find the datatype `YEAR` there. Actually, I searched the net (maybe the wrong keywords) but I couldn't find any help :-(

I am using VS Codium as editor, who doesn't supply the auto-fillin-whatever with `YEAR` after I type
`type: DataTypes.`
there is the option for `DATE`, `INTEGER`, and so on but not for `YEAR`.

**tl;dr**:
Is there any way that Sequelize supports MariaDB's datatype `YEAR`, and if yes, how can I implement it?

Comment: It is not necessary to repeat tag information in the title, and using signatures in your post is expressly against the site guidelines. We know who you are by the username and avatar that are in the bottom right corner of each and every post you make here, so don't add it in the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right, sequelize.js has a YEAR function, but at the time of writing this answer, no [YEAR base type](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/lib/data-types.js), or [MariaDB year type](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/lib/dialects/mariadb/data-types.js).

I couldn't see an [existing issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues), however on the same link you are encouraged to request this feature.